# how to workaround Gsuite caldav api 500 internal error on large calendar

Tags: api, google-workspace, caldav

We're programmatically downloading Google calendar in ICS format using this url : https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/calid/events where calid is the calendarid

On large calendars ( more than around 5000 entries or so), it fails with error 500 Internal server error.

This is not an issue with Exponential backoff, etc... : we can pause,  retry later, implement an exponential backoff, etc... it never works for the calendars that are returning this error, while it works correctly for other calendars.

This is clearly a bug in the Google code that is processing caldav requests.
Probably useless to report it (because Google is never fixing any issue reported), but I'm looking for workaround.
Is there a way to pass parameters to page out the results or to select events between date range etc...
Google caldav api documentation ( https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide ) has nothing.